# SSIS - How to get error messages from Package.Validate()

Tags: c#, ssis

I wrote a utility that dynamically generates SSIS packages and I am using the Package.Validate() call to make sure they are correct before deploying them to the server.  However, when the function fails it just returns DTSExecResult.Failure.  Currently in order to view the error messages I need to open the package in Visual Studio.

Is there a way to retrieve those validation errors in code so I can log those errors and not have to take that extra step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently you need to create a class that implements the IDTSEvents interface.  These methods will fire when the validate() function raises them.